# Mobile @media queries aren't working after uploading to heroku

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, heroku

The title describes it.

I have CSS media queries like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px){...}
```

(also tried without the "only screen and") 
They work flawlessly on localhost with a smartphone. But when i commit the code to heroku, media queries refuse to work and give me the exact same website as on desktop.
Any suggestions?

Comment: P.S. Also, added the viewport metatag. Deleted it. Not working either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {}`
And try to add it in the view not in the css file

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {}
</style>
```

Comment: I had to also add !important to every line for it to work, but it did finally. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this line in your index.html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I don't know if you are using some web framework like I am, but if so you may be running into an issue with how your css files are being incorporated.

I am using Django, and resolved this issue by installing Whitenoise, which is a project that assists in serving static files within Django apps. Heroku has a helpful [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets).

Basically:

1. pip install whitenoise
2. add whitenoise to requirements.txt
3. add 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware' to MIDDLEWARE = [...] in settings.py

Everything seems to be working fine for me now. Shouldn't have to include the media queries in the view or flag any css as important.